# Trouble with wireless TL-WN725N hangs on CTRL_EVENT_CONNECTED

Tags: wireless, raspbian-wheezy

I just got my first Pi (model A) today and I've been struggling with it all day trying to get the latest version (2013-07-26) of Wheezy to connect to my WIFI using a TL-WN725N which is connected to a powered USB hub. I am using WPA security, my SSID is broadcasted and though I have MAC address filtering on I have confirmed that the MAC address is in the white list on the router. When I try to run `wpa_supplicant` here is the output I receive.

```
ioctl[SIOCSIWAP]: Operation not permitted
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWAP]: Operation not permitted
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWAP]: Operation not permitted
rfkill: Cannot open RFKILL control device
wlan0: Trying to associate with 00:22:XX:XX:XX:XX (SSID='MYSSID' freq=2437 MHz)
wlan0: Association request to the driver failed
wlan0: Associated with 00:22:XX:XX:XX:XX
wlan0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 00:22:XX:XX:XX:XX [PTK=CCMP GTK=TKIP]
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 00:22:XX:XX:XX:XX completed (auth) [id=0 id_str=]
```

It just hangs there indefinitely and I'm not sure what to make of it. Here is my `wpa_supplicant.conf` file:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="MYSSID"
    psk="MYPASSWORD"
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    pairwise=CCMP
    auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

Here's my `dmesg` output directly after breaking from `wpa_supplicant`: http://pastie.org/8305148

Also I did run a wireless scan and this was the result:

```
wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 00:22:XX:XX:XX:XX
                    ESSID:"MYSSID"
                    Protocol:IEEE 802.11bg
                    Mode:Master
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:54 Mb/s
                    Extra:wpa_ie=dd1c0050f20101000050f20202000050f2040050f20201000050f2020000
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    Extra:rsn_ie=30180100000fac020200000fac04000fac020100000fac020000
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    Quality=100/100  Signal level=56/100
```

In case it's relevant, I did have some trouble getting Wheezy to recognize the device but after grabbing the 8188eu.ko file and following the instructions from this page: http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=29752 I was able to get it to work.

Hopefully someone has some more ideas for me. I'm pretty close to giving up and trying to find another dongle but it seems like some people have gotten this one to work so I'm not quite there yet.

Answer (score 1):

In situations where the configuration is perfect, often times on the Pi you're let down by your power supply not providing enough current to power the device. This is particularly true if you have a Rev 1 Pi (with only 256 MB of RAM). In this case it looks like there's almost enough current for the Wi-fi adapter, but not quite. So the connection fails when it starts drawing current to decrypt the signal from the access point. Try another power supply, at least 1 A.